# Remove DNS authorization for IP address in Azure

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have a couple of web applications on an Azure server. A client allowed the domain to lapse, and I can no longer access the DNS settings for this domain. The domain's DNS settings (A records, CNAMES) are still authorized in Azure to control traffic for the server's IP address. So, any app I create on this server now resolves to the domain that is no longer under my control.

How do I get myself out of this pickle? Can I change the server's IP address? I have not been able to find out how to do that. Can I de-authorize the DNS settings that now control access to this IP address?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove access to the app from a domain, you just remove the domain from the App Service.

DNS tells users where to go for a particular domain name.
If your app doesn't mention it as a domain, the request won't be routed to it.
Remember that addresses in Azure App Service are shared so it requires that you actually explicitly mention the domain in the app service's configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Under the App services > Custom domains, I removed the hostname. This was yesterday, and I still can't event access the default domain, ______.azurewebsites.net. I suppose all my browsers could be caching the DNS settings but I don't think so.  I think this is because the DNS records were previously authorized for this domain and still have the power to route traffic to my IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out I had a redirect set up in my web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Ok, my issue was that I was redirecting to the domain in my web.config.